# Mac Mountain Lion sometimes work very slow, kernel is overflow, all apps is killed

Tags: linux, macos, mac, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion

Sometimes I have unknown delays in my mac.

Everything works well, but one time in 2-3 hours kernel is overflow,
and I need to wait about from 30 sec to 5 minutes untill it will end, and I will start to work normal.

It is not caused from any app, because I tried to kill all of them, but it is without change.

Any ideas how I can debug it? Kernel process is overflowed in time of delay.

I am a new Mac user, so I can't find.

Answer (score 0):

Some process is using up your RAM or CPU. You can find out which one by running the `top` command in a terminal.

Comment: so i say, this process is from system and its "kernel_task"